# jQuery Convert a string into an object without eval()

Tags: jquery, string, variables, object

I have the following variables:

```
    var opday = [],
        opcategory = [],
        opbarrio = [];
```

Then I have elsewhere:

```
        var myparent = $me.parent().attr('data-filter-group');
```

Supposing myparent returns "category", how can I create an object from that string that references the variable `opcategory`??

For example:

```
var myarray = "op" + myparent;
```

So that I might use that object like so:

```
alert(myarray[2]);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, is there a reason you don't want to use `eval()` ? Since you're using jQuery, you could use [globalEval](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/)

Comment: people tell me that it's evil

Comment: `eval()` is not evil, for what I have heard. If you use it correctly and only on input that you have verified to be correct, it isn't that bad. I mean.. If someone has access to firebug, they can use `eval()` on whatever site they might want, because they have a console which runs javascript for them. :)

Comment: @NoLifeKing Using `eval` in this particular case would be evil, ugly and inefficient.

Comment: @PeterOlson Ah, didn't think about the efficiency.. Didn't know that eval() would be slow. Or maybe I misunderstod the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can address variables declared in global scope as:

```
var myCustomVar = "my value"
, nameOfVar = "myCustomVar"
alert(this[nameOfVar])
// you get "my value"
```

However, this does not work if you stick it inside of the function:

```
var answer = (
    function(){
        var myvar = "the value"
        return this["myvar"]
    }
).call({})
// answer will be 'undefined'
```

Explicitly tying the scope vars to `this` works though:

```
var answer = (
    function(){
        this.myvar = "the value"
        return this["myvar"]
    }
).call({})
// 'answer' will be "the value"
```

Answer (score 3):

I think an object is the best solution for this:

```
var op = {
  day: [],
  category: [],
  barrio: []
};
```

Which you can reference like this:

```
var myarray = op[myparent];
```

There's also a less elegant (read: evil and hacky) solution that only works if `opday` and the others are global variables. All global variables are properties of the `window` object, which allows you to dynamically create and access variables:

```
var myarray = window["op" + myparent];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access a global variable by name, by any means, do it:

```
var myarray = window["op"+myparent];
```

but it would be much better putting all of them into a *map* object.